# Read text file from web and assign to variable in Ruby / Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'd like to read a text file from the web and assign it to a variable in chef / ruby

In powershell I would do something like this:

```
$content = (Invoke-WebRequest http://website.com/string.txt).content
```

Can anyone tell me how this is done in ruby?

Comment: Please read "[ask]". We'd like to know where you've searched and why those haven't helped. This is a common question and has answers across Stack Overflow. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uS3UbQR6GaYsozaF5yQMLmkySY6TO42BIndr2hUW2L4/pub?hl=en&hl=en&output=html is a useful page showing the clients.

Comment: None of those are correct within Chef.

Comment: In Chef, some URIs are easier to handle than others. A lot depends on the MIME type returned. Types other than text/plain may need to be handled by Chef::HTTP::JSONInput or Nokogiri code inside a ruby_block. You could improve your question by including an example of the file to be read, as well as how you plan to use the result. More information often generates better answers, both for you and for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Chef, the correct approach is to use the `Chef::HTTP` client.

```
Chef::HTTP.new('https://example.com/').get('/string.txt')
```

Comment: The OP's question (not tags) are about Ruby, not Chef. [Chef::HTTP](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/Chef/HTTP) is poorly documented in the Chef docs, so your answer would be stronger if you included the API reference. The other answers would still be appropriate for Chef inside a [ruby_block](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html), provided the variables assigned have appropriate scope.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, Chef is mentioned is both the question and title. As for the docs, it is documented on my website in https://coderanger.net/chef-tips/. Using open-uri directly is not recommended as you won't get the TLS policy Chef uses (ex. support for the `trusted_certs/` dir).

Answer (score 1):

Use Ruby's [OpenURI library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html).

```
require 'open-uri'
content = URI.open("http://website.com/string.txt").read
```

Comment: While correct in general, this should not be used within Chef.

Comment: Must use `URI.open` as of Ruby 3.0: `URI.open("http://website.com/string.txt").read`

Answer (score 1):

### Minimal Example

If your URL is really just a plain text file, you can use [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) from the Ruby Standard Library. In your example, you are pointing to "string.txt", but we'll use a real web page just for demonstration purposes.

```
require 'open-uri'
content = open('http://google.com').read
```

This will assign all the contents of the URL to the variable *content*. That may be all you need, but unless you're truly dealing with plain text this approach is generally not useful without further processing.

### Use Nokogiri to Parse HTML

In general, opening a URI that isn't providing an application/json or text/plain MIME content-type gives you a honking big string that isn't all that useful. In such cases, use the [Nokogiri gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri) to do something with the output.

#### Example 1: Extracting Form Elements

For example, to extract the form elements from the Google web page:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

uri = 'http://google.com'
doc =  Nokogiri::HTML(open uri)
doc.css('title, form input').each { |e| puts e }
```

This will filter the page and print only the desired elements. In this case, the result would be:

> ```
> <title>Google</title>
> <input name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1" type="hidden">
> <input value="en" name="hl" type="hidden">
> <input name="source" type="hidden" value="hp">
> <input name="biw" type="hidden">
> <input name="bih" type="hidden">
> <input style="color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top" autocomplete="off" class="lst" value="" title="Google Search" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57">
> <input class="lsb" value="Google Search" name="btnG" type="submit">
> <input class="lsb" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="btnI" onclick="if(this.form.q.value)this.checked=1; else top.location='/doodles/'" type="submit">
> <input id="gbv" name="gbv" type="hidden" value="1">
> ```

#### Example 2: Extracting Plain Text from Paragraph Elements

As another example, consider this snippet. It extracts the content of the first two paragraph tags from the [Ruby Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)).

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

puts Nokogiri::HTML(open uri).css(?p).map { |e| e.text }.slice(0,2).join "\n\n"
```

By slicing and joining the array of paragraph elements, or grepping array elements, you can extract textual data very easily. Using Nokogiri XPath expressions would give you even more power. In this case, the result is:

> Ruby is a dynamic, reflective, object-oriented, general-purpose programming language. It was designed and developed in the mid-1990s by Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto in Japan.
>
> According to its creator, Ruby was influenced by Perl, Smalltalk, Eiffel, Ada, and Lisp.[12] It supports multiple programming paradigms, including functional, object-oriented, and imperative. It also has a dynamic type system and automatic memory management.

You can certainly do a lot more with Nokogiri, but this should get you started. The real point is that *parsing* HTML is usually a better idea than using regular expressions on a text/html response, but of course there are certainly cases where the MIME type of your response may dictate that you use a more minimalist approach.

Comment: While correct in general, this should not be used within Chef.

Comment: @coderanger It depends. While [Chef::HTTP](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/Chef/HTTP) might work for certain MIME types (e.g. text/plain), more complex types would likely need to be handled with [Chef::HTTP::JSONInput](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/Chef/HTTP/JSONInput) or code inside a [ruby_block](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html). Your mileage may certainly vary.

Comment: I don't know where you are getting that from, but no. That middleware is only needed if you want to automatically decode JSON response data, while the question specifically mentions "text file".